# Bazel Build: How to create Python dependency on C++ output?

Tags: python, c++, build, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a C++ program, with a cc_library and cc_binary. They look as follows:

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = ["src/utils.cpp", "src/api.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["include/header1.h", "include/header2.h", "include/header3.h", "include/header4.h"],
    deps = []
)

cc_binary(
    name = "run_app",
    srcs = ["src/app.cpp"],
    deps = [":lib"]
)
```

One of the outputs to app.cpp is `output.xml`. I've created a Python program that takes that output.xml and does some processing to it, then outputs a .png. The py_binary and py_library look like this, and are in the same BUILD file. (I only have one BUILD file and one WORKSPACE file):

```
py_library(
    name = "py_lib",
    deps = [
        #all dependencies for matplotlib. Bazel cannot handle dependency graphs.
        requirement("matplotlib"),
        requirement("pillow"),
        requirement("numpy"),
        requirement("kiwisolver"),
        requirement("packaging"),
        requirement("pyparsing"),
        requirement("cycler"),
        requirement("python-dateutil"),
        requirement("six"),
        requirement("fonttools"),
        requirement("importlib-resources"),
        requirement("contourpy"),
        requirement("zipp")
        ]
)

py_binary(
    name = "xml_to_graph",
    srcs = ["src/xml_to_graph.py"],
    data = [":run_app"],  # a cc_binary which we invoke at run time
    deps = [
        ":py_lib",  # a py_library
    ]
)
```

Ideally, I'd like to have a single binary and run a single build command. Currently, I have to run `bazel build run_app`, then `./bazel-bin/run_app`, then `bazel build xml_to_graph` then `./bazel-bin/xml_to_graph`. I know I can make a bash script doing this easily, but whats the Bazel proper way to do this?

Comment: Under deps you can add the cc_library target for your.  py_binary(
    name = "xml_to_graph",
    srcs = ["src/xml_to_graph.py"],
    data = [":run_app"],  # a cc_binary which we invoke at run time
    deps = [
        ":py_lib",  # a py_library
          "lib",  # a cc_library]
) . C++ library must be built before the Python library can be built, so you should ensure that the cc_library rule appears before the py_library rule in your BUILD.bazel file.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup currently only declares libraries/binaries that `bazel` should build for you. But you are currently not declaring a build-step for actually running the compiled tool.

What is not clear from your question: Do you have to run `run_app` which produces a file consumed by `xml_to_graph` or does the `xml_to_graph` run the `run_app` executable directly? If the latter, your manual building and running of `./bazel-bin/run_app` should not be necessary.

Either way, you can use https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genrule or even better https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/main/docs/run_binary_doc.md#run_binary to run actions during your `bazel build`

Your `BUILD.bazel` could look something like this (untested of course):

```py
cc_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["src/app.cpp"],
    deps = [":lib"]
)

run_binary(
    name = "run_app",
    outs = ["out.xml"],
    args = ["--output-file=$(location :out.xml)"],
    tool = "app",
)

run_binary(
    name = "run_xml_to_graph",
    srcs = [":out.xml"],
    outs = ["out.graph"],
    args = [
        "--input-file=$(location :out.xml)",
        "--output-file=$(location :out.graph)",
    ],
    tool = "xml_to_graph",
)
```